# localectl: Failed to read list of keymaps: No such file or directory

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, localectl

When I run

```
localectl list-keymaps
```

I get

> Failed to read list of keymaps: No such file or directory

How can I fix this error (not I have the `console-data` package installed)? It also happens when I run as root or with `sudo`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in Debian tracked here [#790955 *"localectl list-keymaps : Couldn't find any console keymaps"*](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=790955)

There is not currently a fix nor a workaround.

Comment: Reported at 2015 and it happens for Ubuntu Server 22.04 yet

Answer (score 0):

Found a possible fix at [www.claudiokuenzler.com](https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/1257/how-to-fix-missing-keymaps-debian-ubuntu-localectl-failed-read-list)

In short,

- Download the latest keymaps from [kbd upstream project](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kbd)
- Extract the .tar file (e.g, `tar xzf kbd-x.y.z.tar.gz`)
- Copy the Keymaps folder (or it's content) to /usr/share/keymaps/ (`cp -Rp kbd-x.y.z/data/keymaps/* /usr/share/keymaps/`)
- run `localectl list-keymaps` again to verify